# Как передать параметры класса в другой класс

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Есть класс `Shape` из него надо передать параметры `shapeColors` в другой класс `Draw`.  Никак не могу разобраться, как это сделать. Прошу вашей помощи.

```
Class Shape { 
    constructor(shapeColors) {
      this.shapeColor = shapeColors {
        borderColor : $(".border-color").value,
        fillColor : $(".fill-color").value
      }
    }
  //Какие операции над `shapeColors`
}

Class Draw {}
```

Comment: в коде синтаксическая ошибка и даже не одна

Comment: `shapeColor` обычное свойство, и доступ к нему осуществляется как к любому другому свойству, например через точку: `obj.shapeColor`

Comment: @Grundy это всего лишь псевдокод

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариантов много, можно просто присвоить свойству класса draw свойство класса Shape, но логичнее конечно было бы использовать одно из правил ООП, а именно наследования, унаследуйте класа Shape таким образом.

```
Class Draw extends Shape {}

let draw = new Draw();
```

Таким образом мы унаследовали `shapeColors`.